# Cloth simulation

Tags: three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, cannon.js

I'm trying to create a cloth simulation using `@react-three/fiber` and `@react-three/cannon`.

I created particles that respond to physics. However, I would like to reproduce this behavior on cloth. However, I can't get the effect.

```
 useFrame(() => {
    if (particles.current[0][0]) {
      const geom = meshRef.current.geometry;
      const positions = geom.attributes.position.array;

      positions.forEach((v, vi) => {
        let x = vi % RESOLUTIONX
        let y = Math.floor(vi / RESOLUTIONX)
        if (particles.current[y] && particles.current[y][x].current) {
          geom.attributes.position.setXYZ(vi, ... particles.current[y][x].current.particle.current.position.toArray())
        }
      })


      geom.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
      geom.computeVertexNormals();
    }
  });
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/bart-krakowski/homepage/main?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHero%2Fcomponents%2FPennant%2FPennant.tsx%3A19%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000j3b6hm6x4eslz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000e3b6hqjp8on5r%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000i3b6h1642r5ec%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000g3b6hi09c1a2m%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clm88ztmz000e3b6hqjp8on5r%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000e3b6hqjp8on5r%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clm8905yt00f03b6hz6dr6ncr%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000d3b6hly3ybjnw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FHero%252Fcomponents%252FPennant%252FPennant.tsx%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm8905yt00f03b6hz6dr6ncr%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clm88ztmz000g3b6hi09c1a2m%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000g3b6hi09c1a2m%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm890s5100o33b6hd0ncsq7s%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clm890s5100o33b6hd0ncsq7s%2522%257D%252C%2522clm88ztmz000i3b6h1642r5ec%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000i3b6h1642r5ec%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clm890ny300kh3b6hfab5b8jn%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm88ztmz000h3b6hzr7sspeo%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clm88ztqz001ve4i15g225u7m%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clm890ny300kh3b6hfab5b8jn%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)
[image]

Comment: Check if you've done these:

1.    Set up particles representing the cloth vertices.
2.    Define spring constraints (e.g., using useDistanceConstraint) between neighboring particles.
3.    In each frame, calculate forces acting on the particles (e.g., gravity, spring forces).
4.    Integrate these forces to update particle positions.
5.    Update the cloth geometry based on particle positions.
6.    Implement collision detection and response if needed.
7.    Render the cloth mesh with appropriate materials.